# Objective C delete last NSString in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I am trying to get the last `NSString` from a `NSMutableArray`, and delete it if it's empty.

Here is the code I am using:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([notes.data length]==0){
        [storedText removeLastObject];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

data is the `NSString` and storedText is the `NSMutableArray`. This code deletes the NSString even if it's not empty. I want it to keep the string if it contains text.

Comment: How and where is `data` set? If data isn't set then your logic will fail and delete the item...

Comment: data is a NSString in another class. It is set when I save a textview which then is displayed in a tableview.

Comment: Why don't you check the string before adding to the array, or at least check the item in the array instead of relying on another attribute?

Comment: I am a beginner at this. Can I do something like this instead: if (![storedText containsObject:@""])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  if ([[[storedText lastObject] data] length]==0){
    [storedText removeLastObject];
  }
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

BTW, it seems that your hypothesis that `notes.data` is the same string as the last object in `storedText` is not correct. This leads me to suspect that you have other kinds of errors in your code that you should also investigate. In other words, what you can expect is that your `notes.data` is not correct -- indeed, you should at least "update" it after you remove the last object from the array:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  if ([[[storedText lastObject] data] length]==0){
    [storedText removeLastObject];
    notes = [storedText lastObject]; //-- this will be the *new* last object after removal
  }
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

but I have no clue what you do with `notes.data`, so I do not know if this by itself is enough to bring it back to being consistent with your hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but when I put this code in my project it crashes directly on startup in iOS simulator. What can be the reason?

Comment: which code, the first version or the second one? the first one should not cause any crash. In any case, you should post the crash message. Chances are it does not crash in `viewWillAppear`...

Comment: Both of them cause the same crash message. This is the message I get: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ’-[notes length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffd49604ce0’

Comment: ok, it seems that I was missing an important piece of information: that you are storing `note` objects in the array -- at least, I assume it so now... please try with my edited code...

Answer (score 0):

Ideally before you add any item to `storedText` you would check that it wasn't nil or an empty string, then you wouldn't have the problem.

Otherwise, get the last item from `storedText` and check it (using `isEqualToString:` or a length check) and then remove it if it matches.

Answer (score 0):

Follow what Wain said. Do this.

```
//total array size
int count = [storedText count];
int lastItemIndexInt = count - 1;

//get last object in array which is a string
NSString *str1 = [storedText objectAtIndex:lastItemIndexInt];

if ([str1 isEqualToString:@""] || [str1 length] < 1)
{
   //string is null / blank, remove it
   [storedText removeObjectAtIndex:lastItemIndexInt]; 
}
```